# Using function "arguments" built-in keyword correctly when you don't want to use the rest operator

Tags: typescript

With this function declaration:

```
    someFunc(): void {
      if(__DEV__) {
        this.someOtherFunc.apply(this, arguments);
      }
    }
```

When I call it with parameters, it fails with something like that:

- TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 2.

The normal way would be to use the `rest` operator and forget about `arguments`. I don't want to do it that way cause I'm using a compilation variable `__DEV__` and I want the method to be stripped away at build time when `__DEV__` is false. With the rest operator, typescript add some extra code in the function when targeting ES5.

Is there a way to do it in typescript without having to put `@ts-ignore` everywhere the method is used?

Comment: That's an interesting question. (Side note: `...` isn't, and can't be, an operator.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by defining the type of the method elsewhere:

```typescript
interface YourObject {
    someFunc(...args: any[]): void; // <==== The type of the method goes here
    // ...
}

const obj: YourObject = {
    // This is the implementation of the method
    someFunc(): void {
        // Sadly, the type of `arguments` is not compatible with the array
        // apply expects, so we have to assert it
        this.someOtherFunc.apply(this, arguments as unknown as any[]);
    },
    // ...
}

obj.someFunc(1, 2); // <==== Works
```

I've used `any[]` there, but of course use the relevant types instead.

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gfWwEQFEA1XALngCMkkIQoUBuAWAChWBLFDEGAMyjAIAmkgCuMAPIUAVuCwBvVvGXw0SALYgAYqJRgAFADpjsAOZpy9AJ4BtALoBKcgDck7YA3gB6L-AA8ALxBAfAAKgAWCBhWAA4ISLzwGJHwmslIwPCmSCBo8JFwSipqmhLJPDp6RiYw5pYoto4ubh6sAL6srMjoWEgy5CLiUrJgWCGKLCrevhHseXNJKezqMbSaXFAY7KjwCYsIaeEZRcol2roGTvCu7vATU1M+8ADKUMAQVgA0+0mx8YkAAzMonWGDQAPgCxQSCwyBWm3YFFo8AA7uxkj9YDAoFYTg8nlAYqsrPAQAAPOKjNDfNSohDhKDOKJIeBQNBoHhYdF4qbJOaGM5lAqVMCGQnE-R86ms2ogkBcPJs+C6ADW0JRKFZioa9gczEmKjanzxgvKMBF+iuN0y9weyiexkMeI6LBdrD60gFGnOVQAjN8AEx66bwADqSBgKrQQA)

Targeting ES5, the output is:

```js
"use strict";
var obj = {
    // This is the implementation of the method
    someFunc: function () {
        // Sadly, the type of `arguments` is not compatible with the array
        // apply expects, so we have to assert it
        this.someOtherFunc.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    // ...
};
obj.someFunc(1, 2); // Works
```

Comment: Nice. I was also following the same path by declaring methods at runtime in the constructor. If the class property is declared with arguments, the method implementation doesn't require them. That's the way to go. Unfortunatelly I'm hitting another wall right after cause angular compiler will NOT remove calls to these methods when they do not exists (as they are under a compile time variable). Angular is not removing dead code probably for some good reason like lazy loading bundles. So sad, I will have to put `if (__DEV__) ...` before every single call 